# Express Checkout (digital goods) fails with

Tags: paypal

I am attempting a SetExpressCheckout transaction in LIVE, but it always fails with "We are unable to complete your request at this time." **In the sandbox it works perfectly every time**, so I believe my API call is correct.

Here is the full request:

```
VERSION=97.0
&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout
&RETURNURL=http://www.foo.com/
&CANCELURL=http://www.foo.com/
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=1.00
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=1.00
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Test+Payment
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=TestPayment
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=1.00
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0=Digital
&SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole
&REQCONFIRMSHIPPING=0
&NOSHIPPING=1
&USER=*************************
&PWD=*************************
&SIGNATURE=********************
```

I have a ticket open with Paypal Merchant Support, but they have no clue why it's failing, which amazes me. I have called paypal customer service twice, and they definitely have no clue.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was my mistake. Although I was pointed at the live environment for the SetExpressCheckout call, the subsequent redirect was still going to the sandbox.

My fault...BUT...why can't the paypal developers put a little line of code in there so that when you go to the wrong environment (the system knows EITHER that I had just made the call to Live, then redirected to sandbox, OR at a minimum that the Live environment didn't have a matching token for what I was calling) a concise message is thrown such as "No token found in sandbox environment" or "API call made to Live, but redirected to Sandbox". A message like that would have enabled me to fix my own problem in seconds instead of hours.